# Typeclass subclassing

Tags: scala, typeclass, discriminated-union, subtype

I want to limit a parameter of union type of `A` and `B` types, where `B` is some general type, that will be subtyped. I want to put the objects in this method:

```
def accept[A](a:A)(implicit ev:FooOrBaish[A]){ /* do something */}
```

This is, how do I specify the implicits:

```
case class Foo(i:Int)
trait Baish
case object Bar extends Baish
case class Baz(x:String) extends Baish
class FooOrBaish[A]
object FooOrBaish{
  implicit object FooWit extends FooOrBaish[Foo]
  implicit object BaishWit extends FooOrBaish[Baish]
}
```

Now, I can put in accept `Foo(5)`, but cannot put there `Baz("a")` neither `Bar`, the compiler screams: `error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: FooOrBaish[Baz]`.
Where can I specify the subtype relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change FooOrBaish's type to be contravariant and it works

```
class FooOrBaish[-A]
```